# Generic function problems

Tags: function, generics, rust

I'm playing a bit with generic functions after reading the docs and some  examples but seem it seems I can't make them work. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
pub fn read_uint<T>(buffer: &Vec<u8>, from: &mut usize, consume_data: bool) -> Option<T>
where
    T: num_traits::Unsigned,
{
    const BYTES_TO_READ:usize = core::mem::size_of::<T>();
    ... 
}
```

and I'm calling the function with :

```
let o: u8 = read_uint(buffer, from, false).unwrap();
```

First of all, how does read_uint infer T type? Is it infering it from the left side of the assignment?

I expected the call to be something like:

```
let o: u8 = read_uint<u8>(buffer, from, false).unwrap();
```

The second problem is with the read_uint function itself:

`size_of::<T>()` is giving the error: "can't use generic parameters from outer function". I have been reading about this error too but couldn't make my head around it.

Comment: `read_uint` is not in an outer function, not in the current version of this code.

Comment: You can call it explicitly with a type like this: `read_uint::<u8>(buffer, from, false)`. But yes, you are right, it is inferred from how the variable is used on the left side of the assignment.

Comment: @Peter Hall could you give a helping hand with the size_of error too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a `const` depend on a generic argument. This won't work because the value of a constant must be the same for each call to the function, but `T` could be different each time.

You can easily fix it by changing it to a normal variable binding instead:

```
pub fn read_uint<T>(buffer: &[u8], from: &mut usize, consume_data: bool) -> Option<T>
where
    T: num_traits::Unsigned,
{
    let bytes_to_read = core::mem::size_of::<T>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I see, from other languages I have seen the compiler generating different functions based on T and rewriting the T in the size_of to the generic type (specific for each funtion). Thought rust was the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Notbad Rust _does_ perform monomorphization for generics, this just doesn't work for `const` values. They, as of yet, cannot be dependent on a generic type but this is a restriction that may be lifted in the future.